# In Python I need to read a CSV file and determine the Highest ID number created

Tags: python, csv, file, indexing

I have a CSV file that has lines such as:

```
1, blah, blah, blah
2, blah, blah, blah
3, blah, blah, blah
.
.
.
1000, blah, blah, blah
1001, blah, blah, blah
.
.
.
10000, blah, blah, blah
```

This CSV file could potentially have a million rows.  The first field is the ID Number and each time a new row is added to the CSV file, the program needs to know the highest ID Number from the file. I assume I could just read the last row and add one to the ID Number for the new entry, but what if the ID Numbers were not added to the CSV file sequentially and so the rows were not in order? Is there a quick way to find the highest ID Number without reading the entire row for every single row?

Thanks for any help in pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: No. If you cannot make sure the last row holds the highes ID, you will need to check all IDs, e.g. with `pandas`. A million rows is nothing for a pandas dataframe.

Comment: No, since the data is written sequentially to a file, you cannot read the first column of one line without reading all previous lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the pandas library. Assuming the ID column is called 'ID':

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv(filename)
max_ID = data['ID'].max()
```

Comment: Thank you!  The data will be sorted by ID Number but I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something.  I appreciate all of the useful feedback!